# AngularJS multiple lists that print value and can be toggled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm quite new to Angular (1), and am struggling to understand what's going wrong here.
I want to have two lists (location and style) that print the value when the respective item is clicked. This would concatenate in the

tag: i.e. {{locationTags}} {{styleTags}} = Value from Location li + value from style li.
Together with this, I want the user to be able to only select one item from each list (it would be toggled).

For example, Amsterdam and 222 selected should produce a result of "1test222", and have each 'selected', or toggled.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nick_1002/zt3wpjob/) is the jsfiddle, and here's the code:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="location in myData.location" ng-class="{active:($parent.selected == $index)}" ng-click="$parent.selected = $index;myData.doClick(location)">{{location.city}}</li>
    </ul>
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="style in myData.style" ng-class="{active:($parent.selected == $index)}" ng-click="$parent.selected = $index;myData.doClick(style)">{{style.id}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>{{locationTags}} {{styleTags}}</p>
</div>

    </body>
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.myData = {};
      $scope.myData.location = [{
          city: "None"
    }, {
          city: "Amsterdam"
          , tags: "1"
    }, {
          city: "Argentina"
          , tags: "2"
    }];
      $scope.myData.doClick = function (location) {
          $scope.locationTags = location.tags;
      }
      $scope.myData.style = [{
          id: "111"
          , tags: "test11"
    },{
          id: "222"
          , tags: "test22"
    },{
          id: "333"
          , tags: "test33"
    }];
      $scope.myData.doClick = function (style) {
          $scope.styleTags = style.tags;
      }
      $scope.toggle = function (item) {
          item.selected = !item.selected;
      };
  });
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable ($parent.selected) to keep both selection states.

Try using $parent.selectedLocation and $parent.selectedStyle

Also, you have a name collision in $scope.myData.doClick(). You are overwriting the first function with the second, because you assign it to the same variable.

Try using $scope.myLocation.doClick() and $scope.myStyle.doClick() and edit the rest of the code accordingly

Comment: @nick_1002 the same goes for the `$scope.myData.doClick` function.

Comment: Thanks @tato I got to here, but it's still not functioning fully? https://jsfiddle.net/nick_1002/zt3wpjob/2/